# How do i get rid of these error messages in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am still new to android studio but i cant get rid of these red underlines!! I tried reinstalling Android Studio but it doesn't work. These lines have never been here before and now all of a sudden they are here. It started happening when my laptop unexpectedly shut off when android studio was open. I even started a new project but they still wont go away. Please help because i can't make apps unless this is fixed.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did u try with invalidate Caches/Restart option in File Menu?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Click on File under that u can find this option and try that once

Comment: first clean project and invalidate caches /Restart

Comment: Ok i'll try it out and see if it works

Comment: It made my computer freeze.

Comment: It has to restart the IDE.

Comment: Ok, well I'll wait when it finishes restarting.

Comment: Ok do it didn't restart the ide so I'm opening it myself

Comment: Ok now Android studio isn't starting up

Comment: If it doesn't work, do I have to buy another computer to continue to develop apps?

Comment: I believe it worked. Thank you. This solved my problem and now I can continue making apps.

Comment: @CarloRuiz cool:)